# Get Item from Collection by unique ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-3.0, collections

I have a collection of Contacts that inherits from CollectionBase:

```
public class ContactCollection : CollectionBase{
    //...
}
```

each contact in the collection has a unique ID:

```
public class Contact{
    public int ContactID{
        get;
        private set;
    }
    //...
}
```

I think what I would like to do is something like the following:

```
// get the contact by their unique [Contact]ID
Contact myPerson = Contact.GetContactById(15);

// get all contacts for the customer
ContactCollection contacts = customer.GetContacts();

// replaces the contact in the collection with the 
// myPerson contact with the same ContactID.
contacts.ReplaceAt(myPerson);

// saves the changes to the contacts and the customer
// customer.Save();
```

There is probably a better way...if so, please suggest it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For starters I would change out CollectionBase and use `List<T>`.  CollectionBase was a 1.0 addition that is no longer needed because of Generics.  Actually, you might not even need your `ContactCollection` class, as most of the methods you'll probably need will already be implemented in the generics implementation.

Then you can use LINQ:

```
var item = Collection.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 15);
```

And if you want to keep these, then you can have your `ContactCollection` class just be a wrapper for the `List<T>`  Then the code you actually have to write will be minimal as the generic will do most of the work.

```
Contact myPerson = Contact.GetContactById(15);

// get all contacts for the customer
ContactCollection contacts = customer.GetContacts();

// replaces the contact in the collection with the 
// myPerson contact with the same ContactID.
contacts.ReplaceAt(myPerson);

// saves the changes to the contacts and the customer
// customer.Save();
```

Comment: +1 for addressing the serious architecture concerns displayed

Comment: woah, I just crashed IIS. hm.

Comment: @David if you want to post your code, we can see if we can quickly spot the problem.

Comment: I had replaced `CollectionBase` with `List<Contact>` and left the methods (`Index`, `IndexOf`, `Add`, `CopyTo`, etc.).

Comment: @Kevin, how does this replace that item again?

Comment: Accepted. I'm using `public class ContactCollection : List<Contact>` and `Collection.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 15)`. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
Contact contact = Contact.GetContactById(15);
ContactCollection contacts = customer.GetContacts();
contacts[contacts.IndexOf(contacts.Find(c => c.Id == contact.Id))] = contact;
```

---

This is a bit better...

```
int id = 15;
ContactCollection contacts = customer.GetContacts();
int index = users.FindIndex(c => c.Id == id)
if (index >= 0) contacts[index] = Contact.GetContactById(id);
```

Comment: please, do tell. I've got C# 3.5 at my disposal. (someone gave you a -1 for your suggestion, WTF?) +1

Comment: @David - I suspect (as it wasn't me) that the -1 was for making the suggestion without either providing a link(!) or example.

Comment: The -1 most likely came from the fact that "If you're using LINQ then this is simple" was a very bare answer that didn't solve anything on its own. You were even asking for clarification yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Why not remove the inheritance from CollectionBase, and rely on a composited [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)?

That way, retrieving by unique ID is close to an [O(1) operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), i.e. very fast, compared to linear search over a List.

If each Contact also has a List of ContactIDs, then retrieving them from the Contacts Dictionary is also easy to do.

Some more information about Dictionaries can be found at : http://dotnetperls.com/dictionary-keys

Comment: contacts won't have contacts and the most contacts a customer will have is around 10 with an average of 3...so speed won't be an issue here. +1